# Find and replace files from one directory to another WordPress

Tags: wordpress, bash, find, cp

A site I now manage I found has been corrupted. I would like to keep the content in place, but copy all of the php, txt, and css files from a temporary WordPress installation and move them to the corresponding location using a script.

I don't know how to make a bash or shell script that does something like this:

```
#!/usr/bash
type = [*\.php|*\.css|*\.ini|*\.txt]  

find /temporary/WordPress/ -type f -name '$type' {} + > file-paths-in-temporary-wordpress ;
egrep -o '[a-zA-Z]\.[php|css|ini|txt]' file-paths-in-temporary-wordpress > file-names-of-temporary-WordPress-Installation
find /old/installation/WordPress -type f -name '$type' {} + > file-paths-to-use-as-reference

while read $type in file-names-of-temporary-WordPress-Installation ; do        
    // locating file-names-of-temporary-WordPress-Installation in old WordPress site, copy files  from file-paths-in-temporary-wordpress to the matching locations in the old WordPress installation //
```

I am confused about how to get this to work. Obviously, this is sorely incomplete.

My desired outcome is to have all of the php, ini, css, and txt files from the fresh WordPress installation copied to the corresponding location at the old WordPress site.

I can use:

```
find /temporary/WordPress -type f -name '*.php' -exec cp -fvr {} /old/WordPress/Installation/ + ;
find /temporary/WordPress -type f -name '*.css' -exec cp -fvr {} /old/WordPress/Installation/ + ;
```

..etc.

Any thoughts?

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You should probably use `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just search each directory and copy if there is a match?

```
cp /temorary/WordPress/*.php /new/directory/
cp /temporary/WordPress/*.css /new/directory/
...
```

Comment: It is because there are a LOT of directories to go through and I would rather have a script to save time.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy everything first and remove things you do not need:

```
cp -r /temporary/WordPress /old/WordPress/
find /old/WordPress/ -type f -regex ".*\.\(php\|css\|ini\|txt\)" -exec rm {} \;
```

This might leave empty directories and is fixing things that went wrong (copying files you do not want).

So the right approach is only copying files you need. First go to /temporary/WordPress so you do not need to cut off that dir:

```
cd /temporary/WordPress
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(php\|css\|ini\|txt\)" | while read file; do
   dir="/old/WordPress/${file%/*}"
   mkdir -p "${dir}" 2>/dev/null
   cp "${file}" "/old/WordPress/${file}"
done
```

(Sorry, not tested)